# Shell Script to print a calendar after the user specifies the month and a day

Tags: shell

*****Shell Script*******

> Given a month and the day of the week that's the first of that month, print a calendar for the month. (Remember, number of days in months is different and use \n to go to a new line.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take your time and have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: SO is not a do-my-homework service. Please provide the code you tried and a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Unix has a [cal](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/cal.htm) command especially for this purpose.

By default, `cal` shows the current month's calendar.

```
mayankp@mayank:~/$ cal
   November 2018      
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
             1  2  3  
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10  
11 12 13 14 15 16 17  
18 19 20 21 22 23 24  
25 26 27 28 29 30
```

If you want a calendar for a specific month of a specific year, do this:

```
mayankp@mayank:~/$ cal 1 2018
    January 2018      
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
    1  2  3  4  5  6  
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13  
14 15 16 17 18 19 20  
21 22 23 24 25 26 27  
28 29 30 31
```

This displays the calendar for `January 2018`.

So, your shell script would be:(ex: `calendar.sh`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
month=$1
year=$2

cal $1 $2
```

Run the script like this:

```
mayankp@mayank:~/$ sh calendar.sh 3 2018
     March 2018       
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
             1  2  3  
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10  
11 12 13 14 15 16 17  
18 19 20 21 22 23 24  
25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the assignment specifies that a user must enter which month and which day. The day the user enters will be the start of the month (1)